# Has anyone ever switched between ORM solutions during development?

Tags: .net, orm, repository

At my current job I have implemented the Repository/UoW patterns on top of EntityFramework and DbContext. The only valid reasons I have found for this would be if you didn't want to depend on one particular ORM solution. I just wanted to see if anyone ever did this and, half way through the project (say, a year down the road) decided: "Geez, I'm glad I implemented that Repository Pattern because I need to switch from EntityFramework to NHibernate." Aside from crud and some basic queries with joins (using LINQ) I feel this extra layer of abstraction is annoying since you have to create the table in the database, write a repository, write a service (if you're going for the typical 3 tiered arch) and the necessary front end like a controller and views.

**Update:**

Would like to know if anyone has switch ORM's on a project before and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to do this. I am not aware of any project that actually switched, and switching will actually include a lot of work anyway.
If you read [Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/blog) you will find a lot of points against repositories.

The only reason to do this is when you are developing a framework that can be used with several ORMs based on specific use case.

Moreover, having a repository per table is very wasteful of developer's time.
Even if you go with repositories, having one generic repository with some entity-specific extensions should be more than enough.

Having said all this, I still do use repositories, mostly because I dislike direct references to third-party libraries in unrelated code. But this is a question of preference, and not a best practice I can prove.

Comment: If the entity model exists I can create a basic CRUD operations unit tested repository in 15-20 minutes. I don't feel like that's a waste of time. Please see my answer if you disagree.

Comment: Well for CUD operations one generic repository is enough, why create more. For reads you will probably still use `IQueryable` in one way or another since otherwise any change in requirements will require changes in all layers.

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your repositories. I am a big fan of generic repositories. Most of the time I let the calling code control the Transaction scope and when to commit to the DB but, sometimes I want to do something like control transaction scope and say that every method calls SaveChanges() on my DbContext implictly. This is a situation where a generic repository would not meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of Microsoft blogs that suggest using the repository pattern.

This google search for "entity framework unit of work" back this up.

[entity framework unit of work](http://goo.gl/Yvbs8)

I think whats more important in your code to make sure it's maintainable and flexible is to follow SOLID principals. Most specifically the interface segregation pattern. If you were coding to interfaces then the data repository implementation becomes irrelevant when you are coding to interfaces.

I use Azure Blob Storage to store data sometimes, so I have two implementations of my interface:

`IDtoEntityRepository`

I'm pulling the same data type from two different data stores and each data store has different requirements for working with the data.
So I end up with 1 sql implementation and 1 azure blob storage implementation. The sql implementation happens to be coded with entity framework but I could easily code a new class code with Telerik's Orm called :

```
TelerikOrmDtoEntityRepository
```

Any classes that were coded against IDtoEntityRepository don't care about the implementation. By doing this I have decoupled any data layer implementation details from the calling code.

Comment: **Note: The google search I linked is filtered by past year just to show this pattern is still recommended by Microsoft and is not irrelevant.The search without the filter showed results from 2009 and, I didn't want anyone to suggest that the articles shown in the results were outdated and thus irrelevant.

Comment: Good point. If you need a special ORM or connection interface with different persistence stores, this may come in handy. 

Another example to add here would be a NoSQL solution as well. This is good if you really want to hide what is getting stored into where. _IF_ you want that option.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the minimal objects that you need to deliver fast tested and reliable functional code. Thereafter you may care about refactoring and so forth, then one day, when you decide to change of ORM tool, you'll get your hand dirty playing with the mechanic such as the repository and unit of work design patterns.

Aside, if you're already comfortable with the repository pattern, this might be a good idea to foresee its usefulness as this might enable you not only to change of ORM tool, but perhaps use ADO.NET directly then under certain circumstances.

I believe it is not bad to depend on third party tools such as an ORM or the like, and then I think you want to work for the best rated yet, that is NHibernate, for instance, which I prefer over any other ORM tools that exist. And this is a personal opinion.

The idea behind what I'm saying is not to write a bunch of classes just in case you might need them someday. Write them when you actually need them.

Comment: YAGNI. Currently I am not working on a legacy system, nor do I plan on adding any other external persistence store. And if I wanted to, it would most likely be for BLOB storage if it proves more useful than using SQL Server.

In that case, I might want to know what persistence store I'm actually interfacing with. Another reason is handling transactions, this would be hard to do if I'm intermingling multiple mapping tools.